# display an image from online into imageview of iphone and save in to database

Tags: iphone

I want to dispay an online image in imageview and save it to database
following code display only a particular image. I can also save that image to database.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tvaraj.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/sachin-tendulkar-when-young.jpg&w=231&h=2500&ei=SiKqT9-fKILprQfIudWCAQ&zoom=1"]]];
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];   
img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data1];
NSLog(@"image=%@",img.image);
imageToUse1= img.image;
[image release];

//i want to add this code. this is for 
WebView *Wview=[[WebView alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Wview animated:YES];
```

My requirement is if I click any image that should display in the imageview.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
  UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData: 
  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
  [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/image.jpg"]]];
```

And if you want to use it on an image view just do the following:

// Let's assume the picture is an instantiated UIImageView

```
  [picture setImage: myImage];
  [myImage release];
```

Save image to Database

```
  NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0);   // save this nsdata to ur database.
```

Comment: i have already tried with this code.this is for only one image.my requirement is to select an image from a number of images